# Async validation with redux-thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form, redux-thunk

for my project I am using [Redux-Form](http://redux-form.com/6.8.0/).

I want to validate password and automatically log user to system if password is correct. After user is logged I update some internal redux states. To do that I used redux thunk with actions method.

Problem that I am facing is that redux thunk action fails to return Promise that is needed for async redux-form validation.

This is error I have:

```
asyncValidate function passed to reduxForm must return a promise
```

Does someone knows where is the problem?

Here is code I am using:

**asyncValidate.js**

```
import {logIn} from '../user/actions';

const asyncValidate = (values, dispatch) => {
    return logIn(values.booker.email, values.booker.password);


}

export default asyncValidate
```

**User login action**

```
export const logIn = (email, password) => (dispatch) =>
new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    axios.post('/login_check', qs.stringify({
        _username: email,
        _password: password,
        _csrf_token: CSRF_TOKEN
    }), ajaxConfig)
        .then(response => {
            if (response.data.success !== true) {

                dispatch({
                    type: LOG_IN_ERROR,
                    payload: response.data.message
                });
                reject(response.data.message);

            }
            else {
                dispatch({
                    type: LOG_IN_SUCCESS,
                    payload: response.data.user
                });
                resolve();
            }

        })
        .catch((error) => {
            dispatch({
                type: LOG_IN_ERROR,
                payload: error
            });
            reject(error);
        })

});
```

**EDIT 1:**

Tried code that @Ravindra Ranwala suggested and I still got same error:

@Emrys Myrooin suggested to move code from actions to asyncValidation function but Redux-Form doesn't trigger any error when user (me in this case) enters wrong password.

Here is code for new asyncValidate function:

```
import {LOG_IN_ERROR, LOG_IN_SUCCESS, CSRF_TOKEN} from '../booker/actions';
    import axios from 'axios';
    const qs = require('qs');
    const ajaxConfig = {
        headers: {"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}
    };

const asyncValidate = (values, dispatch) => {
    console.log(values);
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        axios.post('/login_check', qs.stringify({
        _username: values.booker.email,
        _password: values.booker.password,
        _csrf_token: CSRF_TOKEN
    }), ajaxConfig)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            if (response.data.success !== true) {

                dispatch({
                    type: LOG_IN_ERROR,
                    payload: response.data.message
                });
                reject(response.data.message);

            }
            else {
                dispatch({
                    type: LOG_IN_SUCCESS,
                    payload: response.data.user
                });
                resolve();
            }

        })
        .catch((error) => {
            dispatch({
                type: LOG_IN_ERROR,
                payload: error
            });
            reject(error);
        })
    })


    }

    export default asyncValidate
```

**EDIT 2. Updated code from comments**

With this code, as soon as password fields triggers blur event I got this error:

```
Uncaught Error: asyncValidate function passed to reduxForm must return a promise
```

After ajax request is finished I got validation error message that I want to have from beginning but password field is not validated...

This is error after ajax request is finished:

```
asyncValidate.js?9b4c:19 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Bad credentials.
```

asyncValidate function:

```
import {logInError, logInSuccess, CSRF_TOKEN} from '../booker/actions';

import axios from 'axios'
const qs = require('qs')
const ajaxConfig = {
    headers: { 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' },
}

const asyncValidate = (values, dispatch) => {
    axios
        .post(
            '/login_check', qs.stringify({
                _username: values.booker.email,
                _password: values.booker.password,
                _csrf_token: CSRF_TOKEN,
            }), ajaxConfig)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            if (response.data.success)
                dispatch(logInSuccess(response.data.user))
            else
                throw new Error(response.data.message)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            dispatch(logInError(error.message))
            throw error
        })
}

export default asyncValidate
```

Reducer actions:

```
export const logInSuccess = response => ({
    type: LOG_IN_SUCCESS,
    payload: response

});

export const logInError = (response) => ({
    type: LOG_IN_ERROR,
    payload: response


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `logIn` is an action creator that returns an action, here a thunk. So no, the return of `logIn` is not a promise.

I think you should move your async code to the `asyncValidate` function and use the `dispatch` given in parameter to dispatch the actions you want to modify the redux state.

**EDIT**

Your code should look like this :

```
import { logInError, logInSuccess, CSRF_TOKEN } from '../booker/actions'
import axios from 'axios'
const qs = require('qs')
const ajaxConfig = {
  headers: { 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' },
}

const asyncValidate = (values, dispatch) => 
  axios
    .post(
      '/login_check', qs.stringify({
        _username: values.booker.email,
        _password: values.booker.password,
        _csrf_token: CSRF_TOKEN,
      }), ajaxConfig)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.data.success)
        dispatch(logInSuccess(response.data.user))
      else
        throw new Error(response.data.message)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      dispatch(logInError(error.message))
      throw { password: error.message })
    })
```

And in your file `../booker/actions` you should have

```
export const logInSuccess = user => ({
  type: LOG_IN_ERROR,
  payload: user
})

export const logInError = (message) => ({
  type: LOG_IN_ERROR,
  payload: message
})
```

Some explanations:

As pointed by the other answer, you don't have to encapsulate you ajax call into a `Promise` because axios already return a promise. To reject a promise in a `then` function, you can juste throw an error.

An other point is to nether build an action out of the specific `action` file where you define your actions. Otherwise you will have tons a duplicated actions and it's terrible for maintenance.

A last point, you probably never have to explicitly check `aBoolean === true` in a condition. Just do `if(aBoolean)` ou `if(!aBoolean)`. The `===` can be use if you really want to also check that your variable is actually a boolean (again it's very unusual).

Comment: I moved logIn function to asyncValidate function but for some reason validation not triggering. Ajax call executes but there is no validation error (i typed wrong password)

Comment: @jureispro Updated the answer

Comment: thank you for your time and for your help. I updated my code with yours and I still got same error. After blur event on password field async function doesn't "wait" for ajax request to finish and I got error "not promise" error.

Ajax request is triggered and after request is finished I got promise error that I didn't handle promise error. You can check code at Edit 2 paragraph

Comment: @jureispro Sorry made a mistake... You have to remove brackets for `asyncValidate` or add a return statement. Check my answer, I have updated.

Comment: thank you for your help. I tried your code and now I don't have any console errors. Only issue that I have is that password fields doesn't change original state to invalid state. After blur field is valid even with wrong password and when I debug in console I can see error that is throwed

Comment: I see the problem, you should throw an object that contains error messages for each fields that have an error. I'm updating

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151042/discussion-between-jureispro-and-emrys-myrooin).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to return a promise explicitly. thunk becomes useful when you dispatch an action to the store. Try changing your code like this.

```
export function login(email, password) {
    return function(dispatch) {
        axios.post('/login_check', qs.stringify({
        _username: email,
        _password: password,
        _csrf_token: CSRF_TOKEN
    }), ajaxConfig)
        .then(response => {
            if (response.data.success !== true) {

                dispatch({
                    type: LOG_IN_ERROR,
                    payload: response.data.message
                });

            }
            else {
                dispatch({
                    type: LOG_IN_SUCCESS,
                    payload: response.data.user
                });
            }

        })
        .catch((error) => {
            dispatch({
                type: LOG_IN_ERROR,
                payload: error
            });
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. I tried your code and I same error still remains. Problem is that async function doesn't "wait" for axios call to finish

Comment: what is your async function?

Comment: you can see it at original asyncValidate.js inside my post. I import logIn function to asyncValidate function and just call function from there.

Comment: We don't need to handle resolve, or reject explicitly. I updated the answer. could you please try it now.

Comment: I tried and error is still same. problem is that function exist before ajax request is finished

Comment: could you please add some log statements and see the values you are getting inside `then` and `catch`.